# mk-livestatus 1.1.6p1 fails to compile on Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, nagios

When trying to compile CheckMK's livestatus Nagios plugin, I get an error during the "make" process:

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -I../nagios -fPIC -g -O2 -MT livestatus_so-TableLog.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/livestatus_so-TableLog.Tpo -c -o livestatus_so-TableLog.o `test -f 'TableLog.cc' || echo './'`TableLog.cc
TableLog.cc: In member function ‘void TableLog::updateLogfileIndex()’:
TableLog.cc:250:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘struct’
TableLog.cc:250:36: error: ‘d_name’ was not declared in this scope
TableLog.cc:250:42: error: ‘offsetof’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [livestatus_so-TableLog.o] Error 1
```

The relevant part of TableLog.cc:

```
250         int len = offsetof(struct dirent, d_name)
251             + pathconf(log_archive_path, _PC_NAME_MAX) + 1;
```

The source is availalbe at http://www.mathias-kettner.de/download/mk-livestatus-1.1.6p1.tar.gz

There's a mailing list thread about this issue (http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.nagios.checkmk/2560), but it remains unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TableLog.cc was missing the "stddef.h" include file which defines the offsetof() macro.

Simply add

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

To the beginning of TableLog.cc

Answer (score 0):

as like omribahumi said in previous answer, edit `TableLog.cc` file

then comment the 523, 524, 525 lines in `setup.sh` script

```
523      #rm -rf $D

524      #mkdir -p $D

525      #tar xvzf $SRCDIR/livestatus.tar.gz -C $D
```

Then execute the `setup.sh` script once again.